# Geocode an Address within a Bounding Box probably not working properly?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to understand how exactly bounding box is working, but from my tests at the moment it seems that result is returned regardless of the bounding box limits.

I tried various approaches,but it appears that either the flow is working this way or I am missing something. In short, I have tried to put in example request:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-mapview-parameter
mapview in Boston suburban area and search text which is my home address in Bulgaria - few thousand miles away from the bounding box borders. However, I still get a result-my address Geocoded correctly. Since it is out of the bounding box I was expecting either 0 results or some exception. Or there is some parameter in the Response I can use for defining outboxing-for this case that might be the Distnace because I am too far but in addresses close to borders I am not sure if that will be fine.

My URL request:
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=g.k.%20Krasna%20polyana%201%2022%D0%91%2C%201373%20g.k.%20Krasna%20polyana%201%2C%20Sofia&mapview=42.3902%2C-71.1293%3B42.3312%2C-71.0228&gen=9&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ

The result I got:

```
'{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2019-08-16T16:31:38.596+0000"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 0.88,
            "Distance": 7276566.3,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "City": 1,
              "District": 0.88,
              "Street": [
                0.85
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1,
              "PostalCode": 0.56
            },
            "MatchType": "interpolated",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_i2D3cJK.runCacYakfrAxD_yIjQ",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 42.69695,
                "Longitude": 23.28172
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 42.69709,
                  "Longitude": 23.28169
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 42.6980742,
                  "Longitude": 23.2801904
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 42.6958258,
                  "Longitude": 23.2832496
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "жк Красна поляна 1 22Б, 1330 София, България",
                "Country": "BGR",
                "County": "София-град",
                "City": "София",
                "District": "Красна поляна",
                "Street": "жк Красна поляна 1",
                "HouseNumber": "22Б",
                "PostalCode": "1330",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "България",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "София-град",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

I am expecting some standard way to catch the results out of the bounding box. Actually, it seems that either there is no clear value to count on or I am missing something about the way it works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one:

bbox - A type of Spatial Filter. A spatial filter limits the search for any other attributes in the request.

For your example: https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=g.k.%20Krasna%20polyana%201%2022%D0%91%2C%201373%20g.k.%20Krasna%20polyana%201%2C%20Sofia&bbox=42.3902%2C-71.1293%3B42.3312%2C-71.0228&&app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx